# $_POST string from Android volley is same but not equal

Tags: php

my php request is designed to get the status from android apps and then base on the status to change the sql statement

```
$status = $_POST['status'];
    switch ($status){
        case 'Arrived':
        $sql ='update order_list set status=?,arrive_at = convert(varchar, getdate(), 100) where order_key=?';
        break;
        case 'Accident occur, the delivery will be late':
        $sql ='update order_list set status=? where order_key=?';
        break;
        case 'Already Pick Up By Driver';
        $sql ='update order_list set status=?,arrive_at = convert(varchar, getdate(), 100) where order_key=?';
        break;

    }

    echo $status;
    echo strcmp($status,'Already Pick Up By Driver');
```

However I found that $sql never change, finally I got the reason is the string I got from $_POST['status'] is different from what I type, however I test it with postman and the result of last two line echo is :

```
Already Pick Up By Driver
1
```

strcmp($status,'Already Pick Up By Driver') == 1 which mean in php system it is not same, however I print the $status out and it seems 100% same as the string, even the number of blank also same

Comment: `var_dump` them, check length and do view source to see if there are special characters/entities.

Comment: Last time I saw this it had to do with character encoding. Try to convert the string to utf8 before you compare it.

Comment: If I was you I would just send a code, like a simple number for example, to represent each status. Then you're not reliant on descriptions or human-readable formats. Far less likely to get any issues then.

Comment: `case 'Already Pick Up By Driver';` is wrong. Also can just be `case 'Arrived': case 'Already Pick Up By Driver':` since the SQL is the same for those two.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a syntax error, you have a `;` where a `:` is expected

```
case 'Already Pick Up By Driver';
```

should be

```
case 'Already Pick Up By Driver':
```